# Filtering spam to an IMAP folder with postfix, policyd and amavis?

Tags: email, postfix, spam-filter, amavis

Using amavisd-new, I'm successfully marking multiple headers and accurately reporting most spam.

However, right now I'm delivering it to the inbox and I would like to have a Junk folder instead. From time to time I will run sa-learn on these boxes (one for each account). So false negatives could be placed there and the system would learn from that.

I'm not sure if postfix, amavis or policyd is the right place to begin. As I'm using virtual domains, there would be a different folder for each user@domain, and not a general quarantine.

Any thoughts on how to set this up?  I guess I want it to function like gmail or yahoo mail do today, automatically moving suspected SPAM into a junk folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options to accomplish this, and they all largely depend on the delivery agent you are using to do the final delivery to a user's virtual mailbox.

1. If you are using the stock Postfix
   virtual(8) delivery agent, you can't
   accomplish this.
2. If you are using either the Cyrus
   LDA or the Dovecot LDA, you habe two
   more options: You can either use
   their builtin Sieve functionality (a
   quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=sieve+spamassassin+header+) should
   reveal how to parse the
   X-Spam-Status header) and provide a
   global Sieve script or make use of
   recipient delimiters (set
   `recipient_delimiter = +` in
   Postfix' main.cf and have a look at
   the [redirect documentation](http://www.ijs.si/software/amavisd/amavisd-new-docs.html#addrext) for
   amavisd-new).
3. If you are using maildrop, see
   James' answer.
4. If none of this options are
   applicable, you could let
   amavisd-new put those mails to a
   quarantine. OSS quarantine managers
   are scarce, for SQL based quarantine
   I do only know of [MailZu](http://www.ijs.si/software/amavisd/amavisd-new-docs.html#addrext) and
   [MailZu-ng](http://trac.husku.net/mailzu-ng/) for modern
   amavisd-new. [Maia Mailguard](http://www.maiamailguard.com/maia/wiki)
   comes with it's own amavisd-new
   implementation (I don't recommend
   using Maia for various reasons).
   Finally, I've lately been writing a
   combined [quarantine/mailsettings
   management application](http://mailsettings.incertum.net/), but I
   can't give any dates on when this
   one will be finished).

A wholly different approach, given that either your mail volume is low or you have access to some serious hardware, would be to run amavisd-new as a [before queue filter](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_PROXY_README.html), thereby eleminating the need for spam/junk folders or quarantine completely: If a legitimate mail is rejected as spam, the sender will be notified by it's own mail server - since you technically never accepted the mail, you won't be responsible for anything.

Comment: Could I ask why you don't recommend Maia? (I'm a developer for Maia)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to setup something like procmail or maildrop to filter the mail into the correct folder when it gets delivered.

Using maildrop you can have a default system wide config which will check the headers and filter spam into the correct location, with something like this in /etc/maildroprc:

```
if (/^X-Spam-Status: yes) {
    to "Maildir/.Spam"
}
```

change the mailbox location depending on your local setup.

Answer (score 0):

*First of all, sorry as this is not a direct answer to your questions, but rather just posting of working spam-proof postfix configuration.*

I maintain corporate server, including mail. During last few years I've tried different mail servers, numerous configurations and plugins. So far, the normal number of spam that is being actually delivered to one of the users mailbox is in average **1 per week**. Taking into consideration that I have more than a hundred of mailboxes the result is awesome.
Sure, this involves regular checking of mail logs and blocking the IP's of servers that where able to pass postfix, but believe me, I'll better put an IP into the SPAM database manually, than will mess with SPAM filters.

Recently I've posted small article about my AntiSPAM postfix setup in my [blog](http://blog.stranadurakov.com/2009/07/10/antispam-postfix-setup/).

My current configuration uses Postfix with postgrey and Dovecot, both using the same PostgreSQL DB.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't rely 100% on amavisd for dropping mail thought to be spam; I would only mark the subject somehow and still deliver

however, until there, there is greylisting, spf and rbl's which are really great